# Embed youtube video without copy link

Tags: youtube, embed

i have youtube video which is embed as "Unlisted" on my wordpress site.
It is in frame where i am blocking upper bar but the issue is with the lower bar where still there is possibility to click (second mouse button) and copy link. The same is when video is paused.

It is possible to disable it without blocking possibility to play/pause and full screen play?

I am looking for free video platform to embed movie into my wordpress site (course).
If youtube can not do this, what else i can use?

Please help,
Jacek

[image]

[image]

Comment: `It is possible to disable it without blocking possibility to play/pause and full screen play?` = consider create the play/pause buttons separately and block the div that holds the youtube video (i.e. add some javascript code for avoid clicks on the div that contains the youtube video) - or, use a third party solution.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt find any third party solution.

Comment: It's not possible. Even if you did, someone could still open their browser console, and view the URL in the HTML, or using Fiddler. The only way is to download the video and host it on your site, and even then, you can't stop someone from downloading it, or recording their screen.